# resize disk partition which is used by RAID

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, raid, lsblk

I need to shrink the `sdb4` partition, which currently occupies the entire 7TB of my `sdb` drive, in order to create an `sdb5` partition for my application. The challenge lies in the fact that there is a `RAID` `md1` partition on `sdb4` and `sdb4/md1/vg0-root` is mounted to `"/"`. I'm concerned that resizing `sdb4` may have unintended consequences on the `RAID` `md1` partition and my system. Can anyone provide guidance on how to create `sdb5` safely in this scenario?

**Output of `lsblk`:**

[image: lsblk]

**Output of `df -h`:**

[image]

**Output of `parted /dev/sdb`:**

[image: parted]

Answer (score 2):

mdadm metadata (version 1.2) stores the device size (`Avail Dev Size` in `mdadm --examine`). When assembling the RAID, it expects the device to have at least this size. If it's too small because you shrink the partition, it will refuse to use this device for assembly.

It would look like this:

```
# mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 /dev/sda4 /dev/sdb4
md: sdb4 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
md: md_import_device returned -22
```

If this is the only issue, you can still assemble it with `--update=devicesize`:

```
# mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 --update=devicesize /dev/sda4 /dev/sdb4
```

This will update the stored device size in the mdadm metadata and allow things to proceed normally.

This method will only work if the RAID did not actually use the space you cut off. Also since you can't stop or reassemble RAID from a running system, it has to be done from livecd / rescue environment.